# ¿Como puedo mostrar mas productos ya que solo me deja poner 4 OR en la consulta?

Tags: php, android-studio

Si agrego un OR mas a la consulta ya no muestra ningun resultado es para un ListView en android studio de producto alguien que me diga como lo puedo solucionar ya que si agrego el 5 OR a la consulta no me deja continuar repito es para un listview de android strudio donde mostrare productos y necesito dividirlos por categorias

```
/*
* Created by Belal Khan
* website: www.simplifiedcoding.net 
* Retrieve Data From MySQL Database in Android
*/

//database constants
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'erpbd1_refagu03');

//connecting to database and getting the connection object
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

//Checking if any error occured while connecting
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

//creating a query
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pk_articulo, pk_familia, descripcion, marca, prec_costo FROM cat_articulos WHERE pk_familia = 1 OR pk_familia = 2 OR pk_familia = 3 OR pk_familia = 75 ORDER BY descripcion;");

//executing the query 
$stmt->execute();

//binding results to the query 
$stmt->bind_result($pk_articulo, $pk_familia, $descripcion, $marca, $prec_costo);

$products = array(); 

//traversing through all the result 
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['pk_articulo'] = $pk_articulo; 
    $temp['pk_familia'] = $pk_familia; 
    $temp['descripcion'] = $descripcion; 
    $temp['marca'] = $marca; 
    $temp['prec_costo'] = $prec_costo; 
    array_push($products, $temp);
}

//displaying the result in json format 
echo json_encode($products);
```

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de la [Clausula IN](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause) para evitar tantos `OR` en tu consulta, ejemplo: `SELECT pk_articulo, pk_familia, descripcion, marca, prec_costo FROM cat_articulos WHERE pk_familia IN (1,2,3,75) ORDER BY descripcion`

Comment: Sigue sin mostrar nada despues de 5 categorias o 5 numeros